# Pending transactions for 3 days

Tags: mist, pending-transactions, etherdelta

I am getting rather desperate. What can I do ?

https://etherscan.io/txsPending?a=0xf48920e191f304d69f9f55d0db602f7e7fe5a62d

[image]

Comment: For one, you can send the same transaction with a higher gas price.

Comment: @lungj 3 of those 4 transactions have gas prices of 40gwei or above

Comment: Ah. When I loaded the page, there was one tx only and it was with a gas price of 5 gwei. If it was in the screenshot, missed it. Spotty cellphone connection.

Comment: @lungj Not your phone connection's fault, etherscan is actually sometimes not showing the transactions, resetting the "Age" or saying it can't find the transaction hash. I really don't know what to do :/

Answer (score 1):

You sent multiple transactions, each with different nonces. Until the transaction with the lowest nonce goes through, the other ones remain in limbo. You need to replace the 5 gwei/gas transaction which is blocking the rest.

Comment: I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/72tctz/guide_how_to_cancel_a_pending_transaction/ but don't want to import my private key on MEW, how can I speficy the nonce in Mist ?

Comment: I ended up using https://jakubstefanski.com/post/2017/10/ethereum-cancel-pending-transaction/